# What does "schon" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does *schon* mean in this context:

> Schließlich wird die Fahrt langsamer und **schon** hält der Wagen.

Comment: The normal way to say this is *Schließlich wird die Fahrt langsamer und schon hält der Wagen.* The way you wrote it is a bit poetic and leaves out the usually required **es**, too. *…und **es** hält der Wagen schon.* could be a line from a song text.

Comment: @Janka Actually I wrote it exactly as it is in the Delfin Lehrbuch.

Comment: That's very odd. @brainscript edited it because he thought the same way I do. Word order is not important for the meaning here but the usual word order is either *… und der Wagen hält schon*, or *…und schon hält der Wagen*. In contrary *… und [es] hält der Wagen schon* is unusual and poetic.

Answer (score 8):

***Schon*** means ***already*** in this context.

It indicates that the second event (the car halting) happens shortly after the first event (the drive getting slower).